# PUT or PATCH when user can modify either partially or completely?

Tags: api, rest, http

Let's imagine I have an application where users can either completely, or partially, update their profile details in one part of the app.

1. PUT for all requests
2. a PUT (for complete updates) and PATCH (for partial updates) for the requests

In the second scenario I could let the frontend decide whether the full or just a part of the profile was updated. However, this would involve both more code on both the front- and backend.

The first method is on the other hand "easier" to implement. However, is it against certain REST specs / principles?

Answer (score 1):

> is it against certain REST specs / principles?

It depends on how you mean it.

If you are thinking "all profile changes are performed by sending a complete replacement of the profile resource via an HTTP PUT", then yes, that is aligned with REST principles (specifically, it respects the uniform interface constraint -- you are using the HTTP PUT message the same way it is used everywhere else, which means that general purpose clients can interface with your resources).

On the other hand, if, instead of the complete replacement, you are considering sending a partial replacement via HTTP PUT, then that is not consistent with REST principles (because you are deviating from the standardized semantics of HTTP PUT).

---

If HTTP had a standardized "partial PUT" method, using this hypothetical method would be consistent with REST principles.

In other words, REST doesn't really say anything about what messages should be included in the "uniform interface".  It just says that everybody should use those messages the same way.  It's the HTTP standard that says PUT means complete replacement.